# How to properly use internal page links?

Tags: jsx, eslint

I can't figure out the problem I have - can't get any suitable match on Google or in ESLint manual.

Consider page, where I want to have internal link to some section (eg. to the comment section):

```html
...
<a href="#comments">Comments: 3</a>
...
<a name="comments"/>
...
```

On such code I've got 2 problems to solve:

1. Second link has no content (what if I dont want to have content in this situation?).
2. Second link has no href attr (and it shouldn't be 'void', but how to do it if it has no 'href'?)

I can't find any help in web, so I wonder - it's done in a different way or what?

**EDIT**

Specifying doubts:

- I'm using React/JSX
- Problem is with Eslint plugin for JSX: eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y, sorry for not pointing it out =/

Comment: What does this have to do with ESLint?  That's a JavaScript linter, but you are showing HTML‽

Comment: Yea, sorry - it's actually the JSX problem with eslint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't say which HTML version this question is targeted at, I'll assume HTML 5.  The  tag can't be self closing, so you must split it into a start and end tag.  If you don't want content, then don't put something between the tags:

```
...
<a name="comments"></a>
...
```

The next problem is the deprecated `name` attribute.  Use `id` instead:

```
...
<a id="comments"></a>
...
```

This should fix your problems, but you should consider dropping the  tag and put the `id` attribute to whatever comes after and can be used as a target for the  tag with the reference to the `id`.

Comment: thanks! I'm not usually writing in HTML5 and didn't notice that nowadays hash links should point to IDs, not a:name elements..